# ios 8 swift how to design multiple layer using storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm trying to do something a bit complicated and I have a big problem.
So, I have one screen with 3 "layers" each one with a different size (so they are overlapping each other).
Based on the user gestures, I will hide/show them.
Each layer I would like to build it in my storyboard in order to see what I'm putting in, where it will be , etc.

My question: how to work with 3 "layers" knowing that in my storyboard they are all the time visible, so impossible to work on each one of it.
I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you can do the following: select your view/object, in the right panel click the 'Installed' button. Don't forget to uncheck it or it will not compile.

That said, I like to use containerViews when I do stuff like this because I find it much clearer for the next guy that has to edit your storyboard.

Comment: Awesome Mikael. This is what I was looking for about 3 days: the containerView. I didn't  use it before but I just read about it and made a quick demo: is working as expected.